# Gatsby & Graphql: Filter allMarkdownRemark for pages matching a variable

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby

I'm trying to filter all my markdown pages, for pages which match a certain `category`(specified in markdown `frontmatter`) and pages which are not the pages being currently visited. All pages created from markdown though are receiving the same result for `allMarkdownRemark` though and are not filtering any results.

I would like to know how to get all the pages to not have the same result for `allMarkdownRemark`, and would like the results in `allMarkdownRemark` to be filtered

My page query looks something like

```
    export const pageQuery = graphql`
        query ArticleQuery($path: String, $category: String, $title: String) {
            allMarkdownRemark(
                filter: {
                    frontmatter: {
                        category: {eq: $category},
                        title: {ne: $title}
                    }
                },
                sort: {
                    order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] 
                }
            ) {
            ...
```

And my `gatsby-node.js` looks like

```
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);
const { fmImagesToRelative } = require('gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2');
const path = require("path");

exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createPage }, graphql }) => {
    const postTemplate = path.resolve(`src/components/ArticlePage.jsx`);

    const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___title] }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              category
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

    if (result.errors) {
        return Promise.reject(result.errors);
    };

    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
            path: `${node.fields.slug}`,
            category: `${node.frontmatter.category}`,
            title: `${node.frontmatter.title}`,
            component: postTemplate,
            context: {node}
        });
    });
};

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  fmImagesToRelative(node);
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`){
    actions.createNodeField({
        node,
        name: `slug`,
        value: createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages`, trailingSlash: true }),
    });
  }
};
```

All markdown files include something like this in them

```
---
title: "My title"
category: "My category"
---
```

Comment: What's the question/issue?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know how to get all the pages to not have the same
> result for `allMarkdownRemark`, and would like the results in
> allMarkdownRemark to be filtered

In these cases, what is commonly used is a `key` field for all kind of markdown files that you want to group. As you said, `allMarkdownRemark` is a schema inferred by Gatsby (and their transformers and sharps) at the time that you allow it to access to your filesystem so you can't distinguish directly the type of markdown. This is the simplest, cleanest, and less invasive option. You just need to:

```
---
title: "My title"
category: "My category"
key: "pageTypeOne"
---
```

Then, in your queries, you just need to filter for `key` field when needed:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query ArticleQuery($path: String, $category: String, $title: String) {
        allMarkdownRemark(
            filter: {
                frontmatter: {
                    category: {eq: $category},
                    title: {ne: $title}
                    key: {eq: "pageTypeOne" }
                }
            },
            sort: {
                order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] 
            }
        ) {
        ...
```

You can change the string-based approach to a context one if needed in your `createPage` API in your `gatsby-node.js`. Or, depending on your needs, create a filtered query in your `gatsby-node.js`, creating different queries for each page, in that way your `markdownRemark` will be filtered already.

Alternatively, you can add different filesystems ([`gatsby-source-filesystem`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/)) and use the inferred `sourceInstanceName` to get your data:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `pages`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `posts`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/posts/`,
  },
},
```

Then:

```
{
  allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "posts" } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        extension
        dir
        modifiedTime
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't I essentially doing this with category? I don't understand the point of `key`. The page I'm creating is created from a template, but I want to filter for different markdown remarks depending on the category of that page

Comment: The idea is the same, but it's not the purpose of  `category`, the idea is to group different types of pages and get them using the proper `filter`. If you add a `key` (name it whatever you want) you'll be able to get your type of pages depending on the remark. Alternatively, you can use `allFile` and use the `sourceInstanceName` to get your type, but the idea is the same (answer updated).

Comment: > You can change the string-based approach to a context one if needed in your createPage API in your gatsby-node.js._________

I thought that I was doing exactly this, but it's resulting in the same `markdownRemarks ` being filtered on every page. Could you show what you mean by this? (I'm interpreting it as meaning "to use a variable for `key: ` instead of a constant string`_______ And btw, I created the `category` property in order to filter my pages based on category. Is it still incorrect to use `category` in this manner?

Comment: `allMarkdownRemark` stands for all markdown files so, to get different markdown types (pages, posts that have type, etc) you can create different queries in your `gatsby-node.js` and filter them by that `key` field and then, create pages based on that unique query